# Sort vector of int from Highest to Lowest

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector below `vector<int> jobs;`

Within it I have a bunch of numbers lets say [4,6,2,7,262,15,623,9]

How can i sort this vector from numbers highest to lowest? So that the highest numbers are in the front?

I tried using this but it didnt work. Program crashes.

```
struct myclass {
  bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;
```

`std::sort (JobPool.end(), JobPool.begin(), myobject);`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: "Program crashes" is a terrible description. Post the whole code of a program that crashes, if you want to get useful answers, and describe what input you are giving to cause the crash.  Try to trim out as much code as possible from your program.

Comment: Ah isee there is `std::reverse(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());`

Comment: If you use `rbegin` and `rend` then it will do a reverse sort in one go.

Comment: @sonicboom, No need to add that on top. See my link. It has two examples where it sorts in descending order and other examples that can be adapted.

Comment: Why do you think std::sort (JobPool.begin(), JobPool.end()) is from begin to end, while std::sort (JobPool.end(), JobPool.begin()) is from end to begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `begin` and `end` iterators in the wrong order. You should call `std::sort` as:

```
std::sort(JobPool.begin(), JobPool.end(), myobject);
```

Then you should make the comparator actually be one that works in reverse order:

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator()(int i, int j) const { return j<i; }
} myobject;
```

Then you should notice that the standard library already supplies [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater):

```
std::sort(JobPool.begin(), JobPool.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Comment: That will go from lowest to highest though.

Comment: If you want do do it in your original way with the iterators swapped, use reverse iterators: `std::sort(JobPool.rbegin(), JobPool.rend());`.

Comment: Yea i got it now, i was ordering my code the wrong with with begin and end